# Pandas reorder raw content

Tags: python, pandas

I do have the following [Excel-File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ylBKDCNo3srJrwhKBuWa9pMIseBX1LQX62EOlhCSWUs/edit?usp=sharing)

Which I've converted it to `DataFrame` and dropped 2 columns using below code:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(self.file)
df.drop(['Name', 'Scopus ID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Now, My target is to switch all names orders within the `df`.

For example,

the first name is `Adedokun, Babatunde Olubayo`

which i would like to convert it to `Babatunde Olubayo Adedokun`

how to do that for the entire df whatever name is it?

Comment: Is the name string type and always formatted `second_part, first_part`?

Comment: yes it's same format, and regarding the dtypes, i can convert the whole df to be str type instead of object.

Comment: Please refrain from sharing an external file but provide a [mcve], thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the name and reconcat them.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Adedokun, Babatunde Olubayo', "Uwizeye, Dieudonné"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def swap_name(name):
    name = name.split(', ')
    return name[1] + ' ' + name[0]

df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(swap_name)
df
```

Output:

> ```
> >         Name
> >     0   Babatunde Olubayo Adedokun
> >     1   Dieudonné Uwizeye
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to do the operation on "Other Names 1":

```py
df.loc[:, "Other Names1"] = df["Other Names1"].str.split(",").apply(lambda row: " ".join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` accessor:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split(', ').str[::-1].str.join(' ')
print(df)

# Output
                         Name
0  Babatunde Olubayo Adedokun
1           Dieudonné Uwizeye
```